# How to count duplicate rows in Excel?

Tags: excel, duplicates, row

I would like to know how to count duplicate rows in Excel. By duplicate rows I mean whole rows, for example:

| (row number) | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Butter | 2 | 10$ |
| 2 | Pillow | 2 | 10% |
| 3 | Butter | 2 | 9,99$ |
| 4 | Butter | 2 | 10$ |

And I want to have a function, which would say "TRUE" if there are any duplicate rows. In this case rows 1 and 4 are exactly the same, so the function would say TRUE because there is any duplicate.

It should be possible, shouldn't it?

I have tried some combinations of count.ifs etc. but couldn't find the result I want

Comment: `=COUNTIFS(A:A,A1,B:B,B1,C:C,C1)>1`

Comment: @BigBen Sir is spot on, i was going to comment the same. Another alternative: `=MMULT(N(B2:B5&"|"&C2:C5&"|"&D2:D5=TOROW(B2:B5&"|"&C2:C5&"|"&D2:D5)),A2:A5^0)>1`

Comment: Another one, although COUNTIFS is probably the way to go..... `=COUNTA(A1:A4)-COUNTA(INDEX(UNIQUE(A1:C4),,1))>0`

Comment: Sorry but am I too stupid or what? Nothing works for me, it just says error.